# Find & Replace across entire workbook in specific row

Tags: vba, excel

```
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fnd As Variant
    Dim rplc As Variant

    fnd = "April"
    rplc = "May"

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht

End Sub
```

I have the follow code, I need it to find and replace across the entireworkbook but only in the row 30. How would I edit the code to do this?

Comment: Instead of `sht.Cells.Replace` use `sht.Rows(30).Replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

First, don't use variants for fnd and rplc; use Strings.

Second, specify the range you want to do the replace on, rather than just using "Cells".

```
Sub Replacer()
    Const csFnd As String = "April"
    Const csRpl As String = "May"
    Const csRow As String = "A30"

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Range(csRow).EntireRow.Replace _
            what:=csFnd, _
            Replacement:=csRpl
    Next sht
End Sub
```

It's also good practice to use constants at the top of your code to hold unchanging text, rather than putting `variable = "String"` in the body of the code. It's easier to maintain with the constants at the top.